# Selecting a responsive design frameworks

Tags: html, responsive-design

Responsive HTML frameworks. I am starting a new project and need to choose a responsive design framework. The three I have already looked at are Bootstrap, Foundation and YAML4. I am looking for recommendations based on the following: flexibility, support and adoption. I want to make sure I don’t choose a dying project. Any feedback suggestions would be appreciated and please let me know if there are others I should look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) is the first to come to my mind. Probably the *hottest* right now as well. There is one that is very similar that someone suggested to me last week called [Foundations](http://foundation.zurb.com/). Foundations seems to be very similar, and I believe some of the creators of Bootstrap started Foundations.

Believe some of the biggest differences is what CSS they use. Bootstrap uses LessCss, and Foundations is Sass I believe.

Can't speak much for Foundations. Haven't played around with it. But Bootstrap is quick and easy to pick up.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you Bootstrap, it has a very good documentation and it's gonna be always better, because it's open source, developed by twitter and github community (not only).
It is optimized for all browser and device. Very easy to implement and use, you only have to get the row/columns method of paginating.
One of the most interesting feature are javascript plugins, that can easily let you cut jquery code because of existing methods and functions.